# Invoke random method from class

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, static, invoke

If I have something like this

```
IFoo f = FooFactory.CreateFoo1();
```

How can I pick a random `CreateFoo` method to invoke? `FooFactory` is static and contains around 15 different `IFoo` types. I'd like to randomly invoke one of them each time a button is pressed. I tried this

```
var methods = typeof(FooFactory).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static 
                                     | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod);

int index = random.Next(methods.Length);
IFoo randomFoo = (IFoo)(methods[index].Invoke(null, null));
```

But this results in `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException`. How can I invoke a random method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you should change is `typeof(IFoo)` since you want invoke one of the static methods of `FooFactory`

try `typeof(FooFactory)`

PS: *Assuming your methods don't have any parameters (or all have the same number and type of parameters)*

Comment: Whoops sorry, my fault, I have FooFactory there already. I've fixed that in my question.

Comment: @SSL then what is the problem? your code works fine (I tested it) (Assuming your methods doesn't have any parameters)

Comment: You found it. Coincidentally, the 4 runs randomly selected methods that had parameters. The ones I used didn't have any and assumed they were all the same. Edit that into your answer as that was the cause of the problem. Thanks for your help.